# Using a `has_many :through` association when the `:through` model has a complex scope (Possible bug in Rails?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my rails application, I have one particular model which has a complex default_scope, and I am trying to create a has_many relationship on one model which goes through this model. Unfortunately I've been getting strange error messages which seem to be caused by the default scope of the :through model. Here's my setup:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: training_classes
#
#  id            :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at    :datetime        not null
#  updated_at    :datetime        not null
#
class TrainingClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings, class_name: :ClassMeeting, foreign_key: :class_id, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :training_class
  has_many :training_records, foreign_key: :class_id, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :training_class

  scope :with_date, joins("
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (#{ClassMeeting.earliest_dates.to_sql}) as class_meeting
    ON class_meeting.class_id = training_classes.id
  ")
  default_scope with_date.order('class_meeting.start_time ASC')
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: training_records
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  class_id   :integer
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#
class TrainingRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :training_class, foreign_key: :class_id, inverse_of: :training_records
  has_many :attendance_records, inverse_of: :training_record, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :meetings, class_name: :ClassMeeting, through: :training_class # This doesn't work correctly
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: class_meetings
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  class_id   :integer
#  start_time :datetime
#  end_time   :datetime
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#
class ClassMeeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :training_class, foreign_key: :class_id, inverse_of: :meetings
  has_many :attendance_records, class_name: :AttendanceRecord, foreign_key: :meeting_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :training_records, through: :training_class # This doesn't work correctly

  scope :earliest_dates, select('
    class_meetings.id,
    class_meetings.class_id,
    MIN(class_meetings.start_time) as start_time'
  ).group('class_meetings.class_id').order('class_meetings.start_time DESC')
end
```

Note that in these examples, I have removed of the code for simplicity. I'm pretty sure though that everything related to the relationships between these three models is intact. Also, everything else about these models works just fine in my application, it's just the `has_many :x, through: training_class` relationships that aren't working. Here's the error messages I am getting:

```
irb(main):004:0> ClassMeeting.first.training_records
  ClassMeeting Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "class_meetings".* FROM "class_meetings" LIMIT 1
  TrainingRecord Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "training_records".* FROM "training_records" INNER JOIN "training_classes" ON "training_records"."class_id" = "training_classes"."id" WHERE "training_classes"."id" = 1 ORDER BY class_meeting.start_time ASC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: class_meeting.start_time: SELECT "training_records".* FROM "training_records" INNER JOIN "training_classes" ON "training_records"."class_id" = "training_classes"."id" WHERE "training_classes"."id" = 1 ORDER BY class_meeting.start_time ASC
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:246:in `block in exec_query'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:242:in `exec_query'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:467:in `select'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/explain.rb:40:in `logging_query_plan'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/explain.rb:33:in `logging_query_plan'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:159:in `all'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:173:in `find_target'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:333:in `load_target'
        from c:in `load_target'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:87:in `method_missing'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

And:

```
irb(main):006:0> TrainingRecord.first.meetings      
  TrainingRecord Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "training_records".* FROM "training_records" LIMIT 1
  ClassMeeting Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "class_meetings".* FROM "class_meetings" INNER JOIN "training_classes" ON "class_meetings"."class_id" = "training_classes"."id" WHERE "training_classes"."id" = 23 ORDER BY class_meeting.start_time ASC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: class_meeting.start_time: SELECT "class_meetings".* FROM "class_meetings" INNER JOIN "training_classes" ON "class_meetings"."class_id" = "training_classes"."id" WHERE "training_classes"."id" = 23 ORDER BY class_meeting.start_time ASC
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:246:in `block in exec_query'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:242:in `exec_query'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:467:in `select'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/explain.rb:40:in `logging_query_plan'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/explain.rb:33:in `logging_query_plan'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:159:in `all'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:173:in `find_target'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:333:in `load_target'
        from c:in `load_target'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:87:in `method_missing'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'irb(main):007:0>
```

It seems as though the :through relationships are including the `order('class_meeting.start_time ASC')` part of `TrainingClass`'s default scope in their repsective queries. To me, this doesn't seem to be reasonable behavior at all. Is this a bug with Rails? I have been able to make the relationships work by using the :finder_sql relationship option, but that seems to be a rather awkward solution. Does anyone have any idea on how I could fix this? (Maybe a way to make the relationships ignore `TrainingClass`'s default scope?)

Comment: The error seems to suggest that somewhere you have "class_meeting.start_time" instead of "class_meetings.start_time".  Try searching for the singular version.

Comment: @JacobM That's because there is a "class_meeting" table defined as part of the subquery in `TrainingClass`'s `:with_date` scope. The problem is that ActiveRecord is including the `.order` part of `TrainingClass`'s default scope as part of the query (though I really don's see why), but not the :with_date part of the scope. (Sorry if my code is confusing.)